# Jquery slider animation trouble

Tags: jquery, html, css

I learn writing in jquery and I met a problem with animating slider.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ywrscmpo/1/

The problem is the transition, this is ugly and i dont know how to fix it. How to solve it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var lewo = $('.lewo');
var prawo = $('.prawo');

var teraz = 0;

$('.slider-box ul li ').eq(teraz).addClass('aktywny');

$(".lewo").click(function(){
    $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).removeClass('aktywny');
    teraz = teraz - 1;

    if(teraz == -1)
    {
        teraz = 3;
    }

    $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).fadeIn(1000);
    $( ".slider-box ul li" ).eq(teraz).addClass('aktywny');

});

$(".prawo").click(function(){
    $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).removeClass('aktywny');
    teraz = teraz + 1;

    if(teraz == 4)
    {
        teraz = 0;
    }
    $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).fadeIn(1000);
    $( ".slider-box ul li" ).eq(teraz).addClass('aktywny');

});
```

Comment: instead of fadeIn/Out try with simple show/hide and add some css transition on li element, you need to play with it.

Comment: Ok, i will try later :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of `fadeOut()` the next image will show. Instead of `fadeOut()` If you use
`hide()` it will work. The current image will hide immediatle and next image will be in the effect of animation.

```html
<div id="kontener1"> 
      <div class="slider-box">
    
    <ul>
     <div class="lewo"> </div>
     
     <li> <img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/GUAaScC.jpg" alt="1"> </li>
     <li> <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/board_black_line_texture_background_wood_55220_1920x1080.jpg" alt="2"> </li>
     <li> <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/black_background_pattern_light_texture_55291_1920x1080.jpg" alt="3"> </li>
     <li> <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/dark_background_line_surface_65896_1920x1080.jpg" alt="4"> </li>
     
     <div class="prawo"> </div>
    </ul>
 
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){



 var lewo = $('.lewo');
 var prawo = $('.prawo');

 var teraz = 0;

 $('.slider-box ul li ').eq(teraz).addClass('aktywny');

 $(".lewo").click(function(){
  $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).hide();
  $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).removeClass('aktywny');
  teraz = teraz - 1;
  
  if(teraz == -1)
  {
   teraz = 3;
  }
  
  $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).fadeIn(1000);
  $( ".slider-box ul li" ).eq(teraz).addClass('aktywny');
  
    });
 
 $(".prawo").click(function(){
  $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).hide();
  $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).removeClass('aktywny');
  teraz = teraz + 1;
  
  if(teraz == 4)
  {
   teraz = 0;
  }
  $('.slider-box ul li').eq(teraz).fadeIn(1000);
  $( ".slider-box ul li" ).eq(teraz).addClass('aktywny');
  
    });
 $(".lewo").click();


});
</script>
<style>
*, *, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size:0px;
}

.slider-box {
 position:relative;
 width:80%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:100px;
}

.slider-box ul {
 position:relative;
 
 background-color:grey;
}

.slider-box ul li {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:none;
}

.slider-box img {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.slider-box ul .aktywny{
 display:block;
} 

.slider-box ul .lewo, .prawo {
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:grey;
 z-index: 100;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.slider-box ul .prawo {
 right:0;
 top:0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks. But if I want to use Cross-fading img must apply position: absolute?